# Proof of the unbiasedness of the sample autocovariance

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, covariance, autoregressive

I am not sure I can convince myself as to why the sample autocovariance is unbiased. Here is what I have managed thus far, I would appreciate a hint please.

$$\gamma(h) = n^{-1} \sum_{t=1}^{n-h} (x_t - \bar{x}) (x_{t+h} - \bar{x})$$

To prove unbiasedness I tried to take expectations but get stuck
$$n^{-1} \sum_{t=1}^{n-h} \mathbb{E}\big[ (x_t - \bar{x}) (x_{t+h} - \bar{x}) \big]$$
$$n^{-1} \sum_{t=1}^{n-h} \mathbb{E}\big[x_t x_{t+h} - x_t \bar{x} - x_{t+h} \bar{x} + \bar{x}^2\big]$$

$$n^{-1} \sum_{t=1}^{n-h} \Big[\mu^2 - \mathbb{E}\big[x_t \bar{x} - x_{t+h} \bar{x} + var(\bar{x})\big] + \mu^2 \Big]$$

since $\mathbb{E}(\bar{x}^2) = var(\bar{x}) + \mathbb{E}(\bar{x})^2 = var(\bar{x}) + \mu^2$, then

$$n^{-1} \sum_{t=1}^{n-h} \Big[ 2\mu^2 - \mathbb{E}\big[ x_t \bar{x} - x_{t+h} \bar{x} + var(\bar{x}) \big] \Big]$$

This is where I get stuck in my proof. I have assumed independence here between points $x_t$ but don't think the same can be done for the terms where the sample mean is multiplied by any $x_s$ because the sample mean is a function of all sample data.

Any ideas on how to proceed or if I need try another method??

Comment: Can you explain your third step? Particularly, where did you get two $\mu^2$ and $var(\bar x)$from?

Comment: Its in the second to last line $\mathbb{E}(\bar{x}^2) = var(\bar{x}) + \mathbb{E}(\bar{x})^2 = var(\bar{x}) + \mu^2$. The variance in general is equal to $\mathbb{E}(\bar{x}^2) - (\mathbb{E}(\bar{x}))^2$ and since $\mathbb{E}(\bar{x})) = \mu$ the last term becomes $\mu^2$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Still there seems to be some problem in that step. What happened to $\mathbb E(x_tx_{t+h})$?

Comment: Ah so I assume that $x_t$ and $x_{t+h}$ are independent and so $\mathbb E(x_tx_{t+h}) = \mathbb E(x_t) \mathbb E(x_{t+h}) = \mu \times \mu$ due to stationarity

Comment: That's a mistake. They are not independent. That's the whole point of calculating autocovariance. In fact, $\mathbb E(x_tx_{t+h})$ is exactly $\gamma (h)-\mu^2$ (assuming stationarity) which you *estimating* from data (for clarity you can use $\hat \gamma (h)$ for estimated value.

Comment: @Dayne How do you get $\gamma (h)-\mu^2$?

Comment: $Cov(x_tx_{t+h)}=\mathbb E[(x_t-\mu)(x_{t+h}-\mu)] = \mathbb E(x_tx_{t+h})-\mu \mathbb E(x_t) - \mu \mathbb E(x_{t+h})+\mu^2$

Comment: sorry...it should be $\gamma (h) + \mu^2$

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{E}[x_t] = \mathbb{E}[x_{t+h}] = \mu$? Therefore shouldn't we have $\mathbb{E}[x_t x_{t+h}] - 2\mu^2 + \mu^2 =  \mathbb{E}[x_t x_{t+h}] - \mu^2$? Where does the $\gamma(h)$ come from? I thought $Cov(x_t, x_{t+h}) = \gamma(h)$?

Comment: Yes and that's why, $\gamma(h) = \mathbb E(x_tx_{t+h}) - \mu^2$. And so, $\mathbb E(x_tx_{t+h}) = \gamma(h) + \mu^2$, not $0$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I will have another go deriving it and see where I get. Would you be happy to jump into a personal chat to discuss at some point?

Comment: Sure why not but I am myself not very good in such derivations. But would try of course for sake of my own learning.